# How to remove double and triple quotes from CSV file present in S3 bucket?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a folder in which 100 csv files are present. In each csv files there is a column in which all data is in double quote and for some rows there are triple quotes as well.

```
-------------
 | column_name |
 |   "A"       |
 |   "B"       |
 |    ""       |
 |   """       |
 |    ""       |
 |    "A"      |
----------------
```

[image]

I want to clear this as

```
-------------
 | column_name |
 |    A        |
 |    B        |
 |             |
 |             |
 |             |
 |    A        |
----------------
```

[image]

Comment: Those screenshots seem to be from Excel. Excel **irrevocably mangles** CSVs when opening them, so what you see in Excel is no guarantee of what is actually in the files. Please add excerpts of the files copy-pasted from a text editor instead.

Comment: You don't remove them: you *parse* the entire file. One way of allowing a CSV to include a common in a field is to double quote the field, so that commas inside quotes are treated literally, not as field separators. A common way of escaping literal double quotes to be part of a field is to double them: a line like `a,"b"",""c",d` contains three fields, with the values `a`, `b","c`, and `d`.

Comment: And as with any file format, you need to know the conventions used in order to correctly parse the file.

Comment: in text editor it is showing "A","B","",""", and I want A, B, , ,

Comment: Additionally, any sane CSV parser will think that this is a malformed CSV assuming that `"` is the quote character. Here is a one liner to replace it if you are on linux: `aws s3 cp s3://bucket/file.csv /tmp/tmp.csv && sed 's/"//g' /tmp/tmp.csv > /tmp/noquote.csv && aws s3 cp /tmp/noquote.csv s3://bucket/noquote.csv` ... but again ... your file looks very broken.

Comment: This seems to be an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). *Why* do you want to change the way the CSV file is stored? Why can’t you just use the CSV file as-is?